# Fingerprint sensor not working on linux

Tags: asus

When I tried to turn on fingerprint sensor in Linux , it shows that fingerprint device disconnected . I am using Ubuntu 20.4 on Asus vivobook .
I ran the sudo lsusb command and the following was the output
Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN: Fingerprint

Comment: Most fingerprint readers will not work on Linux because the drivers need to be reverse-engineered by volunteers. That said, some do work. Could you [edit] your question to include the full line from `lsusb`? The name of the company is not enough because ELAN makes several hundred different models, most of which are Windows-only 